# Quantifying a certain number of elements in a set

Tags: alloy

So i have a predicate that takes a set as an argument, and so I can do this:

```
all disj t1, t2, t3: set Thing | predicate[t1+t2+t3]
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do this by just specifying the size of the set, so something like

```
all ts: set of 4 Thing | predicate[ts]
```

What I eventually would like to do is find the minimal integer for which the predicate is valid. Is that in any way possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High order quantification is often discouraged as, to my understanding, the Alloy Analyzer can't always deal with them. (it uses skolemization to get rid of them, but those can't always be applied)

I would thus simplify your model as follows :

```
sig Thing{
}

run predicate for exactly 4 Thing
```

In the pred `predicate` evaluate the property your are interested in on the full set of Thing (constrained to contain exactly 4 atoms)  directly.e.g. Thing.field= ....

Btw, I don't think that `all disj t1, t2, t3: set Thing | predicate[t1+t2+t3]` is doing what you expect it to do. Indeed, t1 t2 and t3 are all sets of Thing with the property that they are disjoint sets. t1+t2+t3 thus won't necessarily produce a set of 3 Things.

Comment: Thanks! (the 'set' in the first line shouldn't be there, was a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but a direct expression of what you seem to be asking for

```
all ts: set of 4 Thing | predicate[ts] -- not Alloy
```

would be

```
all ts: set Thing | #ts = 4 implies predicate[ts]
```